# Run parallel test appium with physical devices

Tags: android, selenium, parallel-processing, appium

I've seen a bit everywhere the Selenium Grid solution to run parallel test but I don't know if this works with physical devices or only virtual and what I need is to test on multiple physical devices.

So I tried to do it "my way" for the moment what I have done is creating a selenium server & driver for each of my physical devices and run my tests but the main issue I encounter is that the test are not really parallel ...

- Step 1 Server one open & driver one is created
- Step 2 Server two open & driver two is created
- Step 3 test1 start on driver one until it finish
- Step 4 test1 start on driver two until it finish
- Step 5 test2 start on driver one
- ....

Is there a way to make it really parallel ?

Here is my code :

Create server

```
public static AppiumServer startServer (String deviceName){

    String port="";
    String boostrapPort="";

    switch (deviceName){
        case ONEPLUS_ONE :
            port = ONEPLUS_ONE_PORT;
            boostrapPort = ONEPLUS_ONE_BOOTSTRAP_PORT;
            break;
        .....
    }

    ServerArguments serverArguments = new ServerArguments();
    serverArguments.setArgument("--address", "127.0.0.1");
    serverArguments.setArgument("--port", port);
    serverArguments.setArgument("--bootstrap-port", boostrapPort);

    AppiumServer appiumServer = new AppiumServer(serverArguments);
    appiumServer.startServer();

    return appiumServer;
}
```

Create driver :

```
@BeforeTest(alwaysRun = true)
public void setUp(){
    AppiumServer samsung_S6_server = AppiumServerFactory.startServer(AppiumServerFactory.SAMSUNG_S6);
    if(samsung_S6_server.isServerRunning()) {
        AndroidDriver samsung_S6 = AndroidDriverFactory.getAndroidDriver(appPackage, appActivity, AppiumServerFactory.SAMSUNG_S6_PORT, AppiumServerFactory.SAMSUNG_S6);
        serverList.add(samsung_S6_server);
        driverList.add(samsung_S6);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Server running issue");
    }

    AppiumServer oneplus_one_server = AppiumServerFactory.startServer(AppiumServerFactory.ONEPLUS_ONE);
    if(oneplus_one_server.isServerRunning()) {
        AndroidDriver oneplus_one = AndroidDriverFactory.getAndroidDriver(appPackage, appActivity, AppiumServerFactory.ONEPLUS_ONE_PORT, AppiumServerFactory.ONEPLUS_ONE);
        serverList.add(oneplus_one_server);
        driverList.add(oneplus_one);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Server running issue");
    }
```

The tests :

```
@Test
public void openArticle (){
    for(AndroidDriver driver : driverList){
        WebElement el = driver.findElements(By.id("..."));
        el.click();
    }
}
.....
```